# How to use the Random Function in a if statement, in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Here is my code for a simple coin toss program, I am new to python.

I am not getting any Errors, but the program will not print my "if" statements, it skips straight from input too input.

I am sure there is more intuitve ways to generate a coin toss program, this was just the idea I had.

Any thoughts?

```
import random
print('--HEADS or TAILS--')
print('Welcome Players!')
print('[H=_Heads][T=_Tails]')
print('Please ENTER {H_or_T}')

input("Heads or Tails:")
rand = (random.randint(1,2))

if rand=='1':
    print("Heads Wins!")
elif rand=='2':
    print("Tails Wins!")

input("Press ENTER to Exit")
```

[Here is a screenshot of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVOQg.png)

Comment: You write: `rand = random.randint(1,2)` and then compare this with strings. Look at the name of this function: `randint`. Random __integer__! Why do you compare _integers with strings_??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the name `randint` already suggests, `random.randint(1,2)` **returns an integer** between 1 and 2 (both inclusive).

If you perform `1 == '1'` you **compare an `int` with a `str`**, which is always `False`. You should compare with `1` instead of `'1`'.

You can also drop the `elif`, and use `else`, since we know that it will be `2` if it is not `1`, so:

```
input("Heads or Tails:")
rand = random.randint(1,2)  # no brackets necessary

if rand == 1:  # use an integer, instead of a string:
    print("Heads Wins!")
else:  # else instead of elif
    print("Tails Wins!")
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint(1,2)` returns the value of integer type. [`random.randint(a,b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) document clearly says that it:

> **Returns a random integer N** such that a <= N <= b.

But in your `if` you are comparing it against the value of string type, and hence your conditional statements are failing.

You need to modify your conditional statements as:

```
#          v no quotes here
if rand == 1:
    print("Heads Wins!")
#            v no quotes here
elif rand == 2 :   # Better to simply use `else` 
    print("Tails Wins!")
```